# SQL - Duplicate rows (changing one column)

Tags: sql-server, view, duplicates

I am having hard time trying to create an view that contains duplicated values from a table in SQL Server Management Studio 17.

My table look like this:

```
DATE = datetime 
Product = varchar(10)
Price = decimal(18,2)

Date     | Product | Price 

07-12-17 |    1    | 32

06-12-17 |    24   | 35
```

There are 1-24 products for every day.

I want to create the following view-tabel:

```
Date     | Product | Price 

07-12-17 |    1.1  | 32

07-12-17 |    1.2  | 32

07-12-17 |    1.3  | 32

07-12-17 |    1.4  | 32  

06-12-17 |    24.1 | 35 

06-12-17 |    24.2 | 35 

06-12-17 |    24.3 | 35 

06-12-17 |    24.4 | 35
```

And so on for all 24 products for every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `CROSS JOIN` with `VALUES`

```
SELECT
  t.[Date],
  CONCAT(t.Product,'.',l.num) ProductLabel,
  t.Price
FROM [Your table] t
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) l(num)
ORDER BY t.[Date],t.Product,l.num
```

Variant with `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
  t.[Date],
  t.Product+'.'+l.Label ProductLabel,
  t.Price
FROM [Your table] t
CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT '1' Label UNION ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL SELECT '3' UNION ALL SELECT '4'
  ) l
ORDER BY t.[Date],t.Product,l.Label
```

If you have another table which contains rows with numbers 1-4 then you can use `CROS JOIN` with that table

```
SELECT
  t.[Date],
  CONCAT(t.Product,'.',l.[ID from another table]) ProductLabel,
  t.Price
FROM [Your table] t
CROSS JOIN [Your table with numbers] l
ORDER BY t.[Date],t.Product,l.[ID from another table]
```

If you need only 4 duplicates then you also can use 4 queries with `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT [Date],Product+'.1' ProductLabel,Price FROM [Your table]
UNION ALL SELECT [Date],Product+'.2',Price FROM [Your table]
UNION ALL SELECT [Date],Product+'.3',Price FROM [Your table]
UNION ALL SELECT [Date],Product+'.4',Price FROM [Your table]
ORDER BY [Date],ProductLabel
```

Comment: Getting the following error message "incorrect syntax near 'num'."

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: Try `Variant with UNION ALL`. No, it's version of `SSMS`. Version of SQLServer can be different try to run `SELECT @@VERSION` to show it.

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM)

Comment: I don't know what version of SQLServer it equals. But try the second variant with `UNION ALL` maybe it works.

Comment: I added one more variant into my answer.